# Using javascript setInterval in zend framework

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, reload

I have a user notification data I fetch from the database and i want a div that contains this data to refresh every 2 mins. I am using zend frame. I have a layout that displays this data by using javascript setInterval function but it throws a database exception error everytime the div reloads.

This is my piece of code

```
// layout.phtml

<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function()
        {
            $('.friendrequestcount').load('notification.phtml');
        },
        2000 * 30 * 60
    );

</script>
```

Can you point how I can reload a div in zend framework?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

edit:
I echo out a number in my notification.phtml 
eg echo 8;

and the error message is

Fatal error: Uncaught exception PDOException with message SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameter were bound in ............. link to PDO.php in Zend

Comment: What is the wording of the database error, and please show us `notification.phtml`.

Comment: Sorry but I think the problem is not in your JS, which looks fine, but in your code making the database call.

Comment: I echo out a number in my notification.phtml

Comment: @user879035: Please post the code that is in `notification.phtml`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling (and could be wrong) that you should be using a route path and not the name of your view script in your `load()` URI, eg

```
$('.friendrequestcount').load('controller/notification');
```

You should never directly try to include or otherwise invoke a view script